# Label message is not printing for empty data table

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I want to display message if data table is empty but label is not printing text.
I tried `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "message", "alert('No data found');", true);` But still its not printing any message.

I believe I am downloading file from server in ZIP folder may be that's why I am not able print message ?

Please guide me where I am doing mistake ?

@Adyson Please check my updated code
Business Logic Explanation :

Here we have requirement is: To store multiples file on one button click and it is not possible Because for one HTTP request One Response we can generate so alternatively what I do is : First I Create csv File and store on server latter after completion of csv file generation I am zipping all csv in a single file and able to download. and on page load I am deleting old csv files to avoid duplicacate files.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Order_Files/"));
            int iCnt = 0;
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
                info.Refresh();
                if (info.LastWriteTime <= DateTime.Now)
                {
                    info.Delete();
                    iCnt += 1;
                }
            }
            btnGenerate.Attributes.Add("onclick", "waitdownload();");

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                BindRegion();
                //lblINQ.Text = "";
                //lblQUO.Text = "";
            }
        }
        public void BindRegion()
        {
         //Binding Code
        }
        protected void ddlregion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         //Select Index change code
        }
        protected void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            #region CSV Generation
            DateTime Order_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(deOrderDate.Text);
            var Order_Date_Datemodified = Order_Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");

            foreach (ListItem listItem in ddlDepot.Items)
            {
                int OrderSum = 0;
                int LineSum = 0;

                if (listItem.Selected)
                {
                    #region for INQ
                    if (ddlInqfileType.SelectedItem.Text == "INQ" || ddlInqfileType.SelectedItem.Text == "QUO")
                    {
                        OracleCommand CmdB = new OracleCommand(String.Format(@"//Select Query"
                        , ddlInqfileType.SelectedItem.Text, listItem.Value,
                        (ddlInqfileType.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("ÏNQ") ? deInqDate.Text.ToString() : deQuoDate.Text.ToString()),
                        deOrderDate.Text.ToString()), con);
                        CmdB.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        OracleDataAdapter daBINQ = new OracleDataAdapter();
                        DataTable dtINQ = new DataTable();

                        dtINQ.Columns.Add("DEPOT_CODE", typeof(string));
                        dtINQ.Columns.Add("ROUTE_CODE", typeof(string));
                        dtINQ.Columns.Add("UPLOAD_DATE", typeof(string));
                        dtINQ.Columns.Add("SAP_REGION_CODE", typeof(string));
                        dtINQ.Columns.Add("SAP_SUB_REGION_CODE", typeof(string));
                        dtINQ.Columns.Add("SAP_CUSTOMER_CODE", typeof(string));
                        dtINQ.Columns.Add("SALES_DATE", typeof(string));
                        dtINQ.Columns.Add("PRODUCT_CODE", typeof(string));
                        dtINQ.Columns.Add("ORDER_QTY", typeof(string));
                        dtINQ.Columns.Add("UOM_CODE", typeof(string));
                        dtINQ.Columns.Add("LINE_TOTAL", typeof(string));

                        daBINQ.SelectCommand = CmdB;
                        daBINQ.Fill(dtINQ);

                        if (dtINQ.Rows.Count <= 0)
                        {
                            lblINQ.Text = "No data found for Selected Inquiry date, Please select other date";
                            lblINQ.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            foreach (DataRow dr in dtINQ.Rows)
                            {
                                OrderSum += Convert.ToInt32(dr["ORDER_QTY"]);
                            }
                            foreach (DataRow dr in dtINQ.Rows)
                            {
                                LineSum += Convert.ToInt32(dr["LINE_TOTAL"]);
                            }
                            DataRow row = dtINQ.NewRow();
                            row["DEPOT_CODE"] = "TOT";
                            row["ORDER_QTY"] = OrderSum;
                            row["LINE_TOTAL"] = LineSum;
                            dtINQ.Rows.Add(row);
                            string fileName = "INQ" + listItem.Value + Order_Date_Datemodified + ".CSV";
                            string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Order_Files/" + fileName);
                            Almarai.AlmTextReadWrite.GenerateCSV(filePath.Replace(fileName, ""), fileName, dtINQ, false, false);
                         }
                    }
                    #endregion FOR INQ

                    #region For QUO
                    if (ddlqoutatfileType.SelectedItem.Text == "INQ" || ddlqoutatfileType.SelectedItem.Text == "QUO")
                    {
                        OracleCommand CmdB = new OracleCommand(String.Format(@"//Select Query"
                        , ddlqoutatfileType.SelectedItem.Text, listItem.Value,
                        (ddlqoutatfileType.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("QUO") ? deInqDate.Text.ToString() : deQuoDate.Text.ToString()),
                        deOrderDate.Text.ToString()), con);
                        CmdB.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        OracleDataAdapter daQUO = new OracleDataAdapter();

                        DataTable dtQUO = new DataTable();

                        dtQUO.Columns.Add("DEPOT_CODE", typeof(string));
                        dtQUO.Columns.Add("ROUTE_CODE", typeof(string));
                        dtQUO.Columns.Add("UPLOAD_DATE", typeof(string));
                        dtQUO.Columns.Add("SAP_REGION_CODE", typeof(string));
                        dtQUO.Columns.Add("SAP_SUB_REGION_CODE", typeof(string));
                        dtQUO.Columns.Add("SAP_CUSTOMER_CODE", typeof(string));
                        dtQUO.Columns.Add("SALES_DATE", typeof(string));
                        dtQUO.Columns.Add("PRODUCT_CODE", typeof(string));
                        dtQUO.Columns.Add("ORDER_QTY", typeof(string));
                        dtQUO.Columns.Add("UOM_CODE", typeof(string));
                        dtQUO.Columns.Add("LINE_TOTAL", typeof(string));
                        daQUO.SelectCommand = CmdB;
                        daQUO.Fill(dtQUO);
                        if (dtQUO.Rows.Count <= 0)
                        {
                            lblQUO.Visible = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            foreach (DataRow dr in dtQUO.Rows)
                            {
                                OrderSum += Convert.ToInt32(dr["ORDER_QTY"]);
                            }
                            foreach (DataRow dr in dtQUO.Rows)
                            {
                                LineSum += Convert.ToInt32(dr["LINE_TOTAL"]);
                            }
                            DataRow row = dtQUO.NewRow();
                            row["DEPOT_CODE"] = "TOT";
                            row["ORDER_QTY"] = OrderSum;
                            row["LINE_TOTAL"] = LineSum;
                            dtQUO.Rows.Add(row);
                            string fileName = "QUO" + listItem.Value + Order_Date_Datemodified + ".CSV";
                            string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Order_Files/" + fileName);
                            Almarai.AlmTextReadWrite.GenerateCSV(filePath.Replace(fileName, ""), fileName, dtQUO, false, false);
                        }
                    }
                    #endregion For QUO
                }
            }
            #endregion CSV Generation

            #region ZIP Generation
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                //string fileName = ddlqoutatfileType.SelectedItem.Text + ".csv";
                string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Order_Files/");
                zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.AsNecessary;
                zip.AddDirectoryByName("Orders");
                string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
                foreach (String filename in Directory.GetFiles(directoryName, "*.csv"))
                {
                    zip.AddFile(filename, "Orders");
                }

                // cookies
                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("ExcelDownloadFlag");
                cookie.Value = "Flag";
                cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
                Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
                //cookies
               
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = false;
                string zipName = String.Format("Zip_{0}.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd-HHmmss"));
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipName);
                zip.Save(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

            }
            #endregion ZIP Generation
        }
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblQUO" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: That's a likely explanation. If the request returns a file to download, it cannot also return content for the web page in the same response. The browser will treat it as either a file to download, or something to display, not both (it uses the headers to decide). A HTTP response can only have one content-type.

Comment: @ADyson Oh is there any other approach to achieve same ?

Comment: Well it depends on the precise requirement. It sounds like maybe you want to want to return an error message if there is no data? If so then you should arrange the code so that it doesn't initiate the file download in that situation.

Comment: @ADyson no i don't want to return an Error message i just want to display this message for user to know that no data is present for particular date

Comment: What's the purpose of that? If they open the downloaded file they will already see that it contains no data. But I'd suggest that if there's no data, then there's probably no point in downloading the file, so actually I think what I'm saying makes sense - in that scenario you should show the message _instead of_ initiating the download. (N.B. You might not think of it as an "error" message, but that's irrelevant. The point is that it's feedback to the user which you want to show on the web page. )

Comment: did you put debugger in the condition and check which lines are getting executed?

Comment: @Kavi yes I did and I can see  lblQUO.Text = "No data found" is executing but not displaying on screen

Comment: @ADyson actually on basis of date selection data is coming in CSV format and then into zip and  for no data file. I am not downloading that file. My only concern is: user should know for any particular date there is no data so they can select another date

Comment: Ok. That sounds strange. It's not possible for us to understand what exactly might be going wrong, based on the small amount of code shown. Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please, so we can get an overview of all the code that is being executed when this request runs.

Comment: @ADyson You can check my updated code

Comment: @user14304386 Try adding `return;` after `lblQUO.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;`. By default, Asp.Net would return the form.

Comment: Thanks. But in future please format your code properly when you upload it - it was impossible to work out the flow of the code when the indentation was all over the place like that. If it gets messed up when you paste it, you need to fix it. No-one can understand code when it's in such a mess like that. I fixed it for you this time, but please make the effort yourself in future. Otherwise you're just making it more difficult for people to help you, and I'm sure you don't want that!

Comment: @derloopkat if i use return remaining part will not execute

Comment: @ADyson for sure will format properly sorry for this time.

Answer (score 1):

If the request returns a file to download, it cannot also return content for the web page in the same response. The browser will treat it as either a file to download, or something to display, not both (it uses the headers to decide). A HTTP response can only have one content type.

If you want to return a message to the user when there is no data to download, then you should arrange the code so that it doesn't initiate the file download in that situation.

Currently your code is creating a zip file and setting the HTTP headers which tell the browser to treat the response as an attachment. It does this regardless of whether there is actually any data to download or not.

To prevent this behaviour, simply move that code into your `else` block, so it only does that when the query returned some rows:

```
foreach (ListItem listItem in ddlDepot.Items)
{
  if (listItem.Selected)
  {
    OracleCommand CmdB = new OracleCommand(String.Format(@"SELECT Query"
    OracleDataAdapter daBINQ = new OracleDataAdapter();
    DataTable dtINQ = new DataTable();
    //adding data table columns
    dtINQ.Columns.Add("DEPOT_CODE", typeof(string));
    dtINQ.Columns.Add("ROUTE_CODE", typeof(string));
    daBINQ.SelectCommand = CmdB;
    daBINQ.Fill(dtINQ);

    if (dtINQ.Rows.Count <= 0)
    {
      //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "message", "alert('No data found for Selected Inquiry date, Please select other date');", true);
      lblQUO.Text = "No data found for Selected Inquiry date, Please select other date";
      lblQUO.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
      //calculating SUM of column
      foreach (DataRow dr in dtINQ.Rows)
      {
        OrderSum += Convert.ToInt32(dr["ORDER_QTY"]);
      }

      DataRow row = dtINQ.NewRow();                     
      row["DEPOT_CODE"] = "TOT";
      row["ORDER_QTY"] = OrderSum;
      //Crating CSV and storing on server
      string fileName = "INQ" + listItem.Value + Order_Date_Datemodified + ".CSV";
      string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Order_Files/" + fileName);
         //using dll
      Almarai.AlmTextReadWrite.GenerateCSV(filePath.Replace(fileName, ""), fileName, dtINQ, false, false);
    
      using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
      {
        fileName = ddlqoutatfileType.SelectedItem.Text + ".csv";
        filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Order_Files/");
        zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.AsNecessary;
        zip.AddDirectoryByName("Orders");
        string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);

        foreach (String filename in Directory.GetFiles(directoryName, "*.csv"))
        {
          zip.AddFile(filename, "Orders");
        }

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = false;
        string zipName = String.Format("Zip_{0}.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd-HHmmss"));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipName);
        zip.Save(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
      }
    }
  }
```

Now in the case where there's no data, the server will return a "normal" response containing the HTML generated by the aspx code, and the standard headers to go with it. This should mean that the browser takes the HTML and displays it as a web page, instead of trying to download a zip file.

Comment: Then I would suggest that you still didn't provide enough code for us to reproduce the real issue. All you've shown us is a (incomplete) foreach loop, with no context. We don't know what event it triggered, or what else might be happening in the page's lifecycle (e.g. something which might reset the label's value, or other issue). "Not working" doesn't tell us anything useful, so we can only speculate. Use your debugger to narrow down the issue.

Comment: P.S. As an aside, it shouldn't be necessary to loop through a ddl's items anyway to find the selected value. `ddlDepot.SelectedValue` should give you the selected value automatically without needing to inspect each item individually.

Comment: I am sing Multiple selection drop down list so I am using Forehatch loop

Comment: Yes you are are correct I am updating my whole code

Comment: "Multiple selection drop down list "..ok that explains that then. Fair enough. I don't see any updates to your code though.

Comment: I am formatting my whole code its taking time but sure i will update my code  Please give me some time

Comment: ok thanks. That is significantly different from the simplified version before. But importantly, you haven't taken my advice - you're still initiating the download in all circumstances. You are not preventing it when there are no rows to download (and thus enabling the message to be seen).

Comment: you haven't taken my advice - you're still initiating the download in all circumstances. I change as you suggested but instead of 2 files it was downloading only 1 file so make as at initially position to understand all process what have tried and have done if you will modify this code. for your understanding purpose update same code.

Comment: My exact example was based on your simpler scenario. So can you think of another way? If you have two sets of results then you need to only download if at least one of them has rows, I assume? Or only if both do? Either way you can create a Boolean variable, and set its value according to whether the criteria to return rows are met. Then, later you check that variable value before initiating the download, and decide what to do. It's fairly simple logic. Can you try it? If not I may have more time later to write answers. But it should be easy if you follow that advice and think logically.

Comment: ok got it i am trying with my self as you suggested. But it will very help full if You can write answerer.

Comment: Let me know how you get on. Then if you're stuck still, when I have some free time later I could update my answer.

Comment: I got it now. I am getting result as expected